# Tutorial on migrating Add-ins from ArcGIS 10.x (ArcObjects) to ArcGIS Pro for Microsoft VB.NET?

Tags: arcobjects, references, add-in, arcgis-pro-sdk

I can't seem to find any comprehensive tutorials on migrating (recreating comparable functionality) of 10.x (ArcObjects) VB.Net Add-ins to ArcGIS PRO SDK Add-ins.

- When migrating from Avenue, ESRI offered courses, books and tutorials, etc.
- When Add-Ins were introduced (around the time VBA was dropped) in version 10, ESRI had a complete A-Z online tutorial on migrating from VBA/VB6 to VB.Net and C# including snippets in both VB and C#.
- Both versions 8 - 9 and 10.X used similar ArcObjects Component Object Model so migration path was straight forward in terms of writing the actual to customize ArcGIS using ArcObjects.

I understand that going from a 32bit to a completely new 64bit application required a complete re-write but I was assuming that a comprehensive tutorials on migrating from 10.X Add-ins to Pro Add-ins would be made available by the vendor as was the case in the past. Perhaps I am not looking in the right places; I do find the ESRI sites rather difficult to navigate. **Does anyone know of such tutorial?**

[ESRI confirms that legacy ArcObjects are not compatible with Pro](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/FAQ) stating that a complete re-write is needed but the step-by-step how-to seems to be missing. Amusingly, there is a section titled "Migration from 10.x" in the linked github wiki but it says nothing about migrating at all, rather it answers a short list of with a resounding "No"